# Why there is no std::sort(vector<T>&)

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, iterator

When sorting a vector in C++ you can use STL as:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

As this is very common usage (i.e. providing begin and end iterator) I wonder why there is no sort overload which would accept a reference to the vector e.g:

```
template <typename T>
void sort(vector<T>& vec)
{
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

Comment: Probably because they'd have to define one for each container. More likely it would be `T& vec` not `vector<T>& vec` to work on any container.

Comment: This is part of the Ranges TS, which has a `Range` concept that it can use to constrain the types you can sort. In this case, it actually has a `Sortable` concept that has some additional requirements over a plain `Range`.

Comment: Your function wouldn't work with my `vector<T, BetterAlloc<T>`. Boo.

Comment: `sort()` takes an optional comparator, so `sort(container)` should actually have a second optional comparator parameter in order to be consistent with how all the template algorithms works. But then this would make `sort()` have two arguments, which now collides with the existing `sort()` that takes a beginning and an ending iterator value (plus an optional comparator). I think it's possible to disambiguate the two here, but it would be hard, and is completely unnecessary. It would be cleaner to simply define `sort_container(T, Comparator=std::less<...>)`, IMO.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That's exactly why it _should_ be provided: you can't write it yourself !

Comment: @immibis: How would you sort a `std::map` or a `std::unordered_set`? You'd also expect a specialization for `sort(std::list<T>)`, calling `std::list::sort`. So for consistency you'd really want `std::vector::sort` and `std::deque::sort`

Comment: @MSalters: But I was perfectly happy writing `sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end())`, which I *could* write all by myself... :-S

Comment: You can also sort an array: `char a[10] = {...}; std::sort(a, a+10);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current design of the standard library which splits into algorithms, data structures and iterators has some very nice conceptual implications: Algorithms only operate on iterators, never on containers. That means that algorithms cannot by themselves invalidate iterators, and all iterator invalidation comes through container modification, which must be made explicitly.

This is, for example, why remove-erase requires two components: a non-invalidating rearrangement of a sequence, followed by a container operation to shrink the container.

Moreover, not all ranges come from containers, so expressing algorithms in terms of iterators is closer in spirit to operating on abstract "ranges" than on concrete things that contain ranges.

And of course there's the original argument for complexity: By expressing both algorithms and containers in terms of iterators, the library requires O(*M* + *N*) components where *M* is the number of algorithms and *N* the number of containers, whereas if you had one algorithm per container, you would need O(*MN*) components. Yes, you could use templates, but completely unconstrained templates (e.g. `template <typename T> void sort(T&)` have non-local implications, and constraining templates is hard and subtle (e.g. count the hair on anyone who's ever needed to work with `enable_if`, or face their users, or tried to add "concepts" to C++).